# React Hooks, copied data keeps changing original source data

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a filtering page. I make a call to the api and then I copy the data so that with each filter requests i'm filtering from the original source. But for some reason when i'm filtering it's modifying my source. So when i filter twice its giving me wrong data. I put flags to make sure my reducer isnt' being called again.

```
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react';
import {
  useDispatch,
  useSelector
} from "react-redux";
import {
  useParams
} from "@reach/router"
import {
  fetchSession
} from "../actions/dataActions";
import _ from 'lodash'
import {
  useFormik
} from 'formik';

function PageFilter() {
  const sessionData = useSelector(state => state.sessionData); //redux
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      date: '',
      sessionType: '',
      events: ''
    },
    onSubmit: values => {
      filterData(values) //when i hit submit filter data
    },
  });

  function filterData(values) {
    let tempFilter = [];
    if (values.date != '') {
      sessionData.schedule_by_day.map((c, i) => {
        if (c.date === values.date) {
          tempFilter = [...tempFilter, c];
        }
      });
    } else {
      tempFilter = [...sessionData.schedule_by_day];
    }

    if (values.sessionType != '') {
      tempFilter.map((c, i) => {
        let tempSessionType = [];
        c.session_types.map(s => {
          if (parseInt(values.sessionType) == s.id) {
            tempSessionType = [...tempSessionType, s]
          }
        });
        tempFilter[i].session_types = [...tempSessionType];
        //!!!!!!!
        //this is a problem issue, it keeps changing my original data
        //so when i call this again it's filtering from a modified SessionData
        //!!!!!!!
      })
    } else {
    }
    setFilteredData([...tempFilter])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSession(params.id)); //request data and updates state.sessionData
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    ///when sessionData is updated filter the Data based off default form values which displays everything
    if (_.isEmpty(sessionData) == false) {
      filterData(formik.values)
    }
  }, [sessionData])
```

Comment: `tempFilter[i]= {...tempFilter[i],session_types:[...tempSessionType]}` and you can make use of immer https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing a state mutation with `tempFilter[i].session_types = [...tempSessionType];`. When you update *any part* of state you must copy it first *then* update the property.

It is actually rather unclear what you are really trying to do in this handler. You map a bunch of data, but don't return or save the result. It appears as though you meant to use array::forEach to issue a side-effect of pushing elements into an external array.  That being said, the following is how you would/should copy the element at the specified index and create a *new* `session_types` property object reference so you are not mutating the original reference.

```
tempFilter[i] = {
  ...tempFilter[i],
  session_types: [...tempSessionType],
}
```

Comment: ..thank you that was it, i thought i wasn't doing a state mutation because i used the spread operator, i will have to read more on this issue. I thoought it was okay to use "tempFilter =" because that was a local variable. Am I right to assume "tempFilter = [...sessionData.schedule_by_day];" this is no good either i need to add [tempFilter,..sessionData.]

Comment: @artSir `tempFilter = [...sessionData.schedule_by_day];` would be ok as it is a new array object reference, but the issue arises when you need to also update some nested state; you should copy the object that needs to be updated so it too is a new reference.